# How to compare the length of a list in html/template in golang?

Tags: html, go, equals, go-html-template

I am trying to compare the length of a list in golang html/template. But it is loading forever in html.

```
{{ $length := len .SearchData }} {{ if eq $length "0" }}
    Sorry. No matching results found
{{ end }}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

From documentation,

> {{if pipeline}} T1 {{end}}:   If the value of the pipeline is empty, no
>   output is generated;  otherwise, T1 is executed.  The empty values are
>   false, 0, any     nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice,
>   map, or   string of length zero.  Dot is unaffected.

So if you want to check if the `.SearchData` slice/array/map is empty just use,

```
{{if not .SearchData}} Nothing to show {{end}}
```

Even your code runs fine if string `"0"` is replaced by int `0`

```
{{ $length := len .SearchData }} {{ if eq $length 0 }}
    Sorry. No matching results found
{{ end }}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Q44qyRbKRB

Comment: For some reasons `{{ $length := len .SearchData }} {{ if eq $length 0 }}` is not working in my html template. But `{{if not .SearchData}}` works. But in some scenarios I have to use `eq` with different values[to restrict the results].

Comment: I understand your need to check for other values. I can't think of why it wouldn't work for you :( Must be something outside templates. Are you sure you are passing the intended value for `SearchData`?

Comment: Yeah. I am passing the indented values because `{{if not .SearchData}}` works as expected. I tested with `empty` list and list with some values

Comment: Be careful, in case the result is a number, it returns the total number of digits. Eg, if SearchData is "1234567890", the length will be 10, rather than 1.

Comment: What if "SearchData" is a template function instead, registered with "Funcs"? `{{if not SearchData }}` will throw error "wrong number of args for SearchData: want 1 got 0". A `{{with SearchData .}}` works, but if SearchData returns an empty array, the template in the "with" block is not even rendered so I can't test the array length there.

Answer (score 75):

A shorter version

```
{{ if eq (len .SearchData) 0 }}
    Sorry. No matching results found
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 15):

There is `{{ else }}` for `{{ range }}` Works well for maps as well https://play.golang.org/p/7xJ1LXL2u09:

```
{{range $item := . }}    
    <span>{{ $item }}</span>
{{ else }}
    <span>Sorry no rows here</span>
{{ end }}
```