# Size list with helm

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

Simple question is it possible to get size list with helm and sprig function ?

My list :

```
list:
 - a
 - b
 - c
```

I tried like this :

```
{{ .Values.list | len }}
{{ .Values.list | size }}
{{ .Values.list | length }}
```

Comment: what did it awser ?

Answer (score 16):

See this [How to compare the length of a list in html/template in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967109/how-to-compare-the-length-of-a-list-in-html-template-in-golang).

> While we talk about the “Helm template language” as if it is
>   Helm-specific, it is actually a combination of the Go template
>   language, some extra functions, and a variety of wrappers to expose
>   certain objects to the templates. Many resources on Go templates may
>   be helpful as you learn about templating.

ref: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#template-functions-and-pipelines

So you can use `len` function from `go-template` (`text/template` package).

**Example:**

`values.yaml` contents:

```
list:
  - a
  - b
  - c
```

`template/list.yaml` contents:

```
kind: List
spec:
  len: {{ len .Values.list }}
  items:
{{- range $item := .Values.list }}
    - {{ $item }}
{{- end }}
```